# in telerik asp.net mvc grid control, "after save, insert" confirmation message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

How to show confirmation message after the process of saving or inserting a record to Database?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the client events at telerik demo page. You may get some idea there

Answer (score 0):

The answer would depend on whether you would want a message at row level or at page. For row, you can customize the [RowAction](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/customformatting) event.

If you want the message to be at the page level, I'd go with Tempdata or ViewData approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're doing Ajax binding. If that's the case there is nothing built in to do this. You can hook into the OnSave event, but it's fired before the request is sent to the server. So that's not what you're looking for.

You may be able to do something where you may be able to examine the XmlHTTPRequest object in a global success handler to see what the url was, but I don't XmlHTTPRequest exposes that.

Comment: Yes I am using Ajax Binding, And there is nothing built in ready to use

Comment: @user, I think you misunderstood, What I'm saying is that Telerik doesn't provide any event that happens after the save.

Comment: You may use the success function of the jQuery ajax method method to output your confirm after successfully executed save in db (see this post -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555315/jquery-checking-success-of-ajax-post). Not sure why you need the confirm after the operation is done, though.

Comment: @Dick, @user, yes you can, however, then your confirm box will fire any time the grid does anything, like refresh, filter, sort, etc.