# why my script doesn't get value that I purpose

Tags: php, jquery

in my web there are table content that i give a static value like this

```
<?php
include 'config/koneksi.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Lay Out Penempatan Produk UHT Area Gudang Rak A-F</title>
<link rel="icon" href="http://localhost/wifi/images/RSUP.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/popup-window.css" media="screen">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/popup-window.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>



<script>
    function setvalue(values) {
    document.getElementById('posisi').value = values;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var htmlobjek;
$(document).ready(function(){
  //apabila terjadi event onchange terhadap object <select id=pid>
  $("#pid").change(function(){
    var pid = $("#pid").val();
     $.ajax({
        url: "ambilnamaproduk.php",
        data: "pid="+pid,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
        $("#pname").val(data);
        }
        });
    });
  });
</script>

<script>
var i = $("#myTD").val();
    alert(i);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var htmlobjek;
 $(document).ready(function () {
var i = $("#myTD").val();
      $.ajax({
             url: "cek.php",
             type:'POST'
             data: "i="+i,
             cache: false,
             success: function (data) {
                 $("#cek").val(data);
             }

        });            
});
 var k = $("#cek").val();
if(k = "0"){
 $(document).ready(function () {
                 $(".data").css("background-color", "#00CC00");//green
                 });
                 }
    else{
 $(document).ready(function () {
                 $(".data").css("background-color", "#FF0000");//red
                 });
}                 
 </script>

</head>
<body>
<div>
<input id="cek" name="cek" type="text" />

<table width="1023" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">A1</th>
    <th colspan="2">A2</th>
    <th colspan="2">A3</th>
    <th colspan="2">A4</th>
    <th colspan="2">A5</th>
    <th colspan="2">A6</th>
    <th colspan="2">A7</th>
    <th colspan="2">A8</th>
    <th colspan="2">A9</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="data"> <div align="center"> <input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down', parent : this, width : '270px' });setvalue(this.value);" id="myTD" name="myTD" value="A1.4" /></div></td>
    <td class="data"><div align="center"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });setvalue(this.value);" value="A1.8" /></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });setvalue(this.value);" value="A2.4" /></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });setvalue(this.value);" value="A2.8" /></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });setvalue(this.value);" value="A3.4" /></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });setvalue(this.value);" value="A3.8" /></div></td>

    <td><div align="center">A4.4</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A4.8</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A5.4</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A5.8</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A6.4</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A6.8</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A7.4</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A7.8</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A8.4</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A8.8</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A9.4</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A9.8</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">A1.3</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A1.7</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A2.3</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A2.7</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A3.3</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A3.7</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A4.3</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A4.7</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A5.3</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A5.7</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A6.3</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A6.7</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A7.3</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A7.7</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A8.3</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A8.7</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A9.3</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A9.7</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">A1.2</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A1.6</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A2.2</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A2.6</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A3.2</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A3.6</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A4.2</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A4.6</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A5.2</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A5.6</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A6.2</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A6.6</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A7.2</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A7.6</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A8.2</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A8.6</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A9.2</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A9.6</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">A1.1</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A1.5</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A2.1</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A2.5</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A3.1</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A3.5</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A4.1</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A4.5</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A5.1</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A5.5</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A6.1</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A6.5</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A7.1</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A7.5</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A8.1</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A8.5</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A9.1</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A9.5</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div   class="popup_window_css" id="sample"/>
<table class="popup_window_css"/>
<tr    class="popup_window_css"/>
<td    class="popup_window_css"/>
<div   class="popup_window_css_head"><img src="images/close.gif" alt="" width="9" height="9" />Aksi</div>
<div   class="popup_window_css_body"/><div style="border: 1px solid #808080; padding: 6px; background: #FFFFFF;"/>
<form method="post" action="aksi.php"/>
<table>
    <tr>
     <td> Werehouse Product </td>
     <td><select name="wp">
        <option selected>- Jenis Werehouse -</option>
        <?php
        $q = mssql_query("select WHSName from tblSPDMstWarehouseProduct Order by WHSID"); 

        while ($r = mssql_fetch_array($q)){
        echo "<option value=$r[WHSName]>$r[WHSName]</option>";
        }
        ?>
</select>
</td>
    <tr>
     <td> Posisi</td>
     <td> <input type='text' name='posisi' id='posisi' readonly/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td> Product ID</td>
     <td> <select name="pid" id="pid">
        <option selected = "selected" >- Produk ID -</option>
            <?php
            $q = mssql_query("select ProductID from tblMstProduct Order by ProductID"); 

            while ($r = mssql_fetch_array($q)){
            echo "<option value=$r[ProductID]>$r[ProductID]</option>";
        }?>
        </select>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td> Product Name</td>
     <td ><input type="text" id="pname" name="pname" size="65" readonly/>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td> Production Date</td>
     <td > <input type='text' name="tgl" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2' align='center'>
         <input type='submit' value= 'Save'> 
         <input type='button' value='view' onclick="javascript:ajax_post();"/>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</from>
<div class="popup_window_css_foot">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and then 
i use jquery selector to get that value and use ajax to execute that value like this

```
 var htmlobjek;
     $(document).ready(function () {
         var i = $("td").find("td.data").val();
          $.ajax({
                 url: "cek.php",
                 data: "i",
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (data) {
                     $("#cek").val(data);
                 }
             });     
     });
```

in cek.php of course like this

```
<?php
$posisi =  $_POST[i];

$val = mssql_num_rows(mssql_query("SELECT*FROM tblTrnProduct WHERE Posisi = '$posisi'"));

echo"$val";
?>
```

according to the answer before, yes it work. but in single table. i have checked my html structure(it's okay). after i modified into complex table same case happen again.

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 You could do this, it is however not recommended. Instead he should use `data-value=""` .. But this is only valid in HTML5

Comment: I didn't see OP did set the value @brain you are right.

Comment: why dont you get the value like this .. $(".data").attr("value")..

Comment: @AndriansyahAndri If you `alert` the `i` before the ajax call. What do you get as the value?

Comment: @AndriansyahAndri I updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qxQW/117/) 
It didn't work without the `table`and `tr` tags.
In your full code make sure you close the `tr`tag where the `.data` is.

Comment: @Brainfeeder sory, for the first time i think when it work in single table it's wil work in many table too. BUt after i implement it many table same case happen again...

Comment: I notice some other thing in the updated code above. You load jquery 3 times. jquery.min.js is enough. But you will have to place it before you load the pop-up javaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `<td class="data">` you forgot the `</tr>` .

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function setvalue(values) {
        $('#posisi').val(values);
    }

    var htmlobjek;
    //apabila terjadi event onchange terhadap object <select id=pid>
    $("#pid").change(function(){
        var pid = $("#pid").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "ambilnamaproduk.php",
            data: "pid="+pid,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                $("#pname").val(data);
            }
        });
    });

    var i = $("tr").find("td.data").attr('value');
    $.ajax({
         url: "cek.php",
         type:'POST'
         data: {"data": i},
         cache: false,
         success: 
         function (data) {
             $("#cek").val(data);
         }
    });

    var k = $("#cek").val();
    if(k = "0"){
        $(".data").css("background-color", "#00CC00");//green
    }
    else {
        $(".data").css("background-color", "#FF0000");//red
    }

});
```

In cek.php your 'i' should be available as `$_POST['data']`.

FYI:
If you have multiple rows with a value, or multiple tables with a value in the rows of those tables you should write the code different. Please see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2exM/).

However if there are a lot of values, there will be a lot of ajax calls.
A better solution would be to add the value to a hidden input. Please see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FZSbH/).

Hope it helped you out.

Comment: Do in single row? or single table ? You probably should put the ajax in a for each loop if you need each td value on the page.

Comment: Check the 2 jsFiddle links I added to my answer. I explain how to check multiple rows/tables .. As long as the `td` has the `data` `class` it will look for a value in them.

Comment: ih ave implement your advice, but i got a problem in cek.php
you said in jsFidlle like this    
$_POST['value'][0]; // A1.4
$_POST['value'][1]; // A1.5

but it's not work, what you suggest?

Comment: In your php do `print_r($_POST);` to see what you get. Don't forget to put everything in a `form` with an `id` if you went for the hidden field solution.

Comment: i have a problem to manage event, how to record the output in 
<input id="cek" name="cek" type="text" />
after this process have been finish
 var htmlobjek;
     $(document).ready(function () {
         var i = $("td").find("td.data").val();
          $.ajax({
                 url: "cek.php",
                 data: "i",
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (data) {
                     $("#cek").val(data);
                 }
             });     
     });

after i loaded in my browser input cek have a value 0 always. c'z this code run before ajax finish..

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555315/jquery-checking-success-of-ajax-post), and [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931836/should-i-use-done-and-fail-for-new-jquery-ajax-code-instead-of-success-and)

Comment: mean my ajax-jquery succes i got the data that i want, the problem how to manage my script"$(#Cek).val()" run after my ajax.jquery finished. c'z in my page all script run in same time

Comment: put `var k = $("#cek").val();` in the succes callback. But it is deprecated. you should use `.done` .. I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hKSqX/) again. But i think you should do more of an effort to try and learn yourself. Start reading the jQuery docs and don't just copy everything.

Comment: yes tq i got it... now i wil modified that with many row in one table

Comment: i try to improve this web to handle click event. But i have another problem. in this question. i have tried the step you advise me before. when i use alert still nothing happen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007858/why-this-script-cannt-work

Answer (score 1):

try this, hope it will usefull

```
 var j = $("td").find("td.data").val(); //make sure this will returning value 
 $.ajax({
      url: "cek.php",
      type:"POST",
      data: { i: j },  //Or try { i: $("td").find("td.data").val()},  
      cache: false,
      success: function (data) {
          $("#cek").val(data);
      }
 });
```

In php

```
$posisi =  $_POST['i'];
```

example form [jQuery website](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
  $.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
    .done(function(data) {
      alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly try to fix this:

```
var i = $("td").find("td.data").val();
...
data: "i",
```

to

```
var i = $("td").find(".data").attr('value');
...
data: "i="+i,
```

Comment: @AndriansyahAndri And if you try `var i = $("tr").find("td.data").attr('value');`

Comment: @Brainfeeder nothing change...:(

Comment: debug then, step by step :) write alert(i); after variable set, and see what you got, then go to next row..

Answer (score 0):

just try this=

```
$.ajax({
                 url: "cek.php",
                 data: { "data": i},
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (data) {
                     $("#cek").val(data);
                 }
             });
```

ANd in php
you can do like below:

```
$data = $_POST['data']; //you will get your value
```

Comment: @AndriansyahAndri: first it should work, if not just try to put it like " data: { "data": i}," also updated my post.

Comment: @AndriansyahAndri Did you link to the jquery.js file?

Comment: @SureshKamrushi use 2 ajax query will influence this problem?
c'z before this script i use another ajax for my related combobox
check my all code here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jnmc9ps5nvxea2b/code.php

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problem with your javascript function 
1) Your variable

```
data: "i",
```

should be

```
data: i,
```

2) Secondly you did not mentioned type of ajax method wether it is GET or POST, in AJAX by default type will be GET if you don't mention it. Hence in your case you are passing type is GET and trying to access variable as POST. So Add this line to your AJAX call

```
type:'POST',
```