# Simple success/error return with ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Just starting to learn about ajax although I am running into trouble trying to return a success message in an array.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#delete').on('click', function () {
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        $.ajax({
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: $form.serialize()
        }).done(function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                alert('Saved!');
            } else {
                alert('Some error occurred.');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<?php
$array = array();
$array['success'] = TRUE;
echo $array;
?>
```

response.success should refer to $array['success'] correct?

Comment: Check your consoles Network tab and see what the status of that request is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to echo your array, which will just spit out "Array".

Instead you need to encode your array as JSON and echo that out.

Change this:

```
echo $array;
```

To this:

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

Also you probably need to add your `dataType` in your ajax params so jQuery auto-parses the response:

```
dataType : 'json' // stick this after "data: $form.serialize()" for example
```

Also, here's a good post to read on how to properly handle success/errors with your ajax calls (thanks @Shawn):

[Jquery checking success of ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555315/jquery-checking-success-of-ajax-post)

Comment: I would also recommend that you check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555315/jquery-checking-success-of-ajax-post OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555315/jquery-checking-success-of-ajax-post

Comment: @Shawn That answer recommends `success` and `error` which have been deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.

Comment: @jszobody No, the success and error options are NOT deprecated. the success and error METHODS are deprecated. two totally different things.

Comment: @KevinB You're absolutely right, I misread that other answer. Will update.

Comment: @user756659 Was this helpful? Is your issue resolved?

Comment: Sorry, was eating... echo json_encode($array); is still returning the false alert.

Comment: If you still have issues, do some basic debugging. Look at the network tab in dev tools to see what the server response is. Do an `alert(response)` or `console.log(response)` in your success handler to see what you got back. Let us know, we'll be happy to help if you have more details.

Comment: Works as expected. Thank you... really appreciate it.  Time to dig into this some more, but something as simple as this really helped.  You wouldn't know of a good tutorial/walkthrough off hand would you?  I will need to return and use some values so that is the next step in this process, but it appears I am correct in terms of the array format for returns.

Comment: @user756659 You are absolutely correct in using arrays for your return (passing through json_encode of course). Look up some jQuery ajax tutorials, there are a boatload. Good luck!